# Referencing a component with different scope - Android Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

So I've got this scenario in Android where I have AppComponent, which is a @Singleton. One of my modules, which needs to have a custom scope, @ActivityScope I'm calling it, provides an object which it instantiates and whose constructor requires another object which is provided by AppModule. This is a problem, because when I try to reference AppModule from this module I get an error because one is scoped as @Singleton and the other one as @ActivityScope.
I'm having trouble trying to apply what I read online about subcomponents, which seem the way to go, to my particular case. Can I get any hint?

Comment: I have recently published this video tutorial. It might help you with structuring your components and modules: https://youtu.be/cx6pCIbOqtI

Comment: I recommend Dependent Component https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2#dependent-components-vs-subcomponents

Comment: Have you checked here https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents